# Junk Mail Folder Missing

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013, outlook-web-access

Although you may wonder why I would miss it, I can't see my **Junk E-Mail** folder in Outlook 2013. If I sign in to my account through Outlook Web Access I can see that it is present and has a number of messages in it:

[image]

Is it possible that I somehow hid this in the Outlook client?  I have verified my settings below:

[image]

**Edit**: I have tried re-creating my profile which has no effect. I have also tried creating a folder under my Inbox named *Junk E-Mail*. When I do that, Outlook complains that a folder by that name already exists. Yet I still can't see it!

Comment: When you figure out how you got rid of it you need to answer this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/577221/outook-2013-with-outlook-com-using-eas-exclude-junk-email-folder) earlier in the day from someone who wants to hide it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com) tool from Microsoft. Refer this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c7b2b4f5-dd85-428a-9944-074ca06e4387/missing-junk-mail-folder) for howto's and also this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/657365/inbox-suddenly-hidden-in-outlook-2010/657370#657370). Below are procedure for enabling hidden folder from  Microsoft forum.

1. Launch MFCMAPI tool on the user’s client.
2. Go to Session -> Logon and Display Store Table
3. Select the outlook profile of the user and double-click “Mailbox - your user name”
4. Expand "Root Container"
5. Expand "Top of Information Store"
6. Highlight the Junk E-mail folder in MFCMAPI
7. Locate the `PR_ATTR_HIDDEN` property
8. Check whether the value is `False`. If not, please double click it, uncheck Boolean option in order to change it to `False`
9. Reopen Outlook to check this issue

Comment: Fixed! I can't upvote this enough. It's been broken for years - longer than my original post. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble.  I have several Gmail accounts that I accesses through Outlook and none of them had junk email folders.

I found a great link that walked me right through getting my junk mail folders back.  Here it is:  http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/gmailroot.htm#root

Mine are all working now.  This is really simple.  You just have to go to where you set up new accounts. Double Click on the particular account that you've already set up in Outlook. Then just follow the instructions in the link above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would be beneficial to post the instructions from the link here and provide the link for reference in case the link goes dead in the future.

Comment: Please don't just link. Include the relevant information from the link. If the site ever goes down, your answer is useless. Read [answer].