# Inbox suddenly hidden in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

While using my Outlook 2010 in Windows 8, all of a sudden my Inbox folder got invisible. But still i can see the messages in Inbox folder. But i don't know how to show the Inbox folder again.

Any ideas?

[image: Inbox invisible picture]

Comment: arent you only the single user whom using your outlook?if not check whether the inbox permissions was not restricted at exchange/permission tabs

Comment: Can you see it if you switch to Folder List in the Navigation pane by pressing `Ctrl + 6`?

Comment: Did you tried MfcMapi method?

Comment: @Vignesh4303: I am the only user using Outlook. I was using for more than 2yrs.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath: What's the MfcMapi method? I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Microsoft KB Article ([924226](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924226))  regarding this hidden folder issue. Microsoft says to use [MFCMAPI](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2953). You will get a step by step instruction from [here](http://desigeek.com/blog/amit/2007/01/17/solved-case-of-the-invisible-folder-in-outlook-and-exchange/)